# VB - Binary Search Algorithm to Display Multiple Results (2D Array)

Tags: .net, vb.net, search, binary

I am writing a program in VB that will sort a contact list (2D array) from a file and will then use the `Binary Search Algorithm` to find names `starting with` the `user input`. I then display the names found, with the rest of their contact info. The problem is that the `Binary Search Algorithm` only searched for **one** name. I need to find **all** of the names that `start with` the `user input`.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim found As Boolean = False
Dim search as String = txtInput.Text

Do
    middle = CInt((first + last) / 2) 'calcuate the middle position of the scope

    If contacts(middle, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search) Then 'if the middle name starts with the search String
        found = True 'name was found
    ElseIf contacts(middle, 1).ToLower < search Then 'if the search name comes after the middle position's value
        first = middle + 1 'move the first position to be 1 below the middle
    ElseIf contacts(middle, 1).ToLower > search Then 'if the search name comes before the middle position's value
        last = middle - 1 'move the last position to be 1 above the middle
    End If

Loop Until first > last Or found = True 'loop until the name is not found or the name is found

If found = True Then
    For x = 0 To 4 'display the whole list of data for that name
        txtDisplay.Text += contacts(middle,x).padLeft(15)
    Loop 
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to create another array to keep track of the names found.

Think of it like this: you find a name, and you want to find another one. Well, the rest of the names **have** to be above and/or below the name found.
So, use a while loop to check if the names above and below match the input, and if they do, add them to an array.

First, create a procedure that will determine the size of the array needed to hold all of the names (need to set a size before you can set values):

```
'make sure the array is passed as ByRef because it needs to be changed
Private Sub determineSize(ByVal middle As Integer, ByVal search As String, ByRef foundNames() As Integer) 

    'middle1 and middle2 as the positions (above and below) of the middle position in the search scope
    Dim middle1 As Integer = middle, middle2 As Integer = middle 
    Dim foundTrack As Integer = 0 'number of names found

    Do While contacts(middle1, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)
        foundTrack += 1 '1 more name has been found

        If middle1 > 0 Then 'if there are any positions above the current one
            middle1 -= 1 'move up 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    If middle < UBound(contacts, 1) Then 'if there are more names below the current one
        middle2 += 1 'this will help to not have a duplicate name from the other list

        Do While contacts(middle2, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)

            foundTrack += 1 'Add 1 to the name found tracker.

            If middle2 < UBound(contacts, 1) Then 'if there are any positions below the current one
                middle2 += 1 'move the position down to check for another name on the list
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    ReDim foundNames(foundTrack - 1) 'set the size to be 1 less than the names found
End Sub
```

Then create a procedure that will find all the names and assign those positions to the `foundNames` array:

```
Private Sub FindNames(ByVal middle As Integer, ByVal search As String, ByVal foundNames(,) As String)

    Dim foundTrack As Integer = 0 'number of names found
    'middle1 and middle2 as the positions (above and below) of the middle position in the search scope
    Dim middle1 As Integer = middle, middle2 As Integer = middle 

    Do While contacts(middle1, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)
        foundTrack += 1 '1 more name has been found
        foundNames(foundTrack - 1) = middle 'set the position in the array to be the position of the name found

        If middle1 > 0 Then 'if there are any positions above the current one
            middle1 -= 1 'move up 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    If middle < UBound(contacts, 1) Then 'if there are more names on the list below the current position
        middle2 += 1 'this will help to not have a duplicate name from the other list

        Do While contacts(middle2, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)

            foundTrack += 1 'Add 1 to the name found tracker.

            If middle2 < UBound(contacts, 1) Then 'if there are any positions below the current one
                middle2 += 1 'move the position down to check for another name on the list
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Then just edit your previous `Binary Search Algorithm` to incorporate these procedures:

```
Dim found As Boolean = False
Dim search as String = txtInput.Text
Dim foundNames() As Integer 'array that holds the row position of each of the found names

Do
    middle = CInt((first + last) / 2) 'calcuate the middle position of the scope

    If contacts(middle, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search) Then 'if middle name starts with search string
        found = True 'keep track of the fact that the name was found.
        Call determineSize(middle, search, foundNames)
        Call findNames(middle, search, foundNames)
    ElseIf contacts(middle, 1).ToLower < search Then 'if the search name comes after the middle position's value
        first = middle + 1 'move the first position to be 1 below the middle
    ElseIf contacts(middle, 1).ToLower > search Then 'if the search name comes before the middle position's value
        last = middle - 1 'move the last position to be 1 above the middle
    End If

Loop Until first > last Or found = True 'loop until the name is not found or the name is found

If found = True Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(foundNames)
        For j = 0 To 4
            txtDisplay.Text += contacts(i,j).padLeft(15)
        Loop
    Loop 
End If
```

Now you have the positions in an array so you can sort it if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

The binary search will terminate "somewhere in the list of values that match". If you expect there are multiple values that might match, you need to work backwards from that point (towards A) until you don't get a match, and again forwards (towards Z). This is how you find all the partial matches. If you don't care about the order in which they are displayed, you could change the last part of your code to (something like):

**edited to include some bounds checking:**

```
If found = True Then
    lb = 0
    ub = UBound(contacts)
    if middle > lb Then
      ii = middle
      While contacts(ii, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)
        ii = ii - 1
        if ii < lb Then Exit While
      End While
      firstContact = ii + 1
    Else
      firstContact = lb
    End If

    ii = middle + 1
    If middle <= ub Then
      ii = middle
      While contacts(ii, 1).ToLower.StartsWith(search)
        ii = ii + 1
        if ii > ub Then Exit While
      End While
      lastContact = ii - 1
    Else
      lastContact = ub
    End If

    numMatching = lastContact - firstContact + 1

    Dim matchingContacts(1,1)
    ReDim matchingContacts(1 To numMatching, 0 To 4)

    For ii = 1 To numMatching
      For jj = 0 To 4
        matchingContacts(ii, jj) = contacts(firstContact + ii - 1, jj).padLeft(15)
      Next jj
    Next ii

End If
```

This should find the range of matching contacts, and create a new array that contains just those contacts. I did not test this - so please forgive typos (I don't often write VB). 
I added some boundary checking; no guarantee that it's "perfect" now...

Comment: You can do that with a simple change to my code ... I will update it.

Comment: I appreciate the short amount of code compared to the accepted answer, but yours exceeded array boundaries. I could probably figure out why and adjust it, but his works with copy and paste so I'm going with that. Thanks, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know at what line the boundary was exceeded? I can see how it would happen if your binary search matched just the first or last name in the contact list. I have added some checking - it does make the code a bit longer...

Comment: It broke at `matchingContacts(ii, jj) = contacts(firstContact + ii - 1, jj).padLeft(15)` and jj exceeded bounds. I would also change `ReDim matchingContacts(1 To numMatching, 0 To 4)` to `ReDim matchingContacts(numMatching - 1,5) because there is an error there.`